# How do I make Flutter table stretch vertically

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, cross-platform

I am new to Flutter and I cannot make my table take all the available space vertically.

Here is the code:

```dart
         home: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(),
         body: Table(
           children: [
             TableRow(
               children: [
                 TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('1')),
                 TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('2')),
               ]
             )
           ]
         )
     )
```

This is what I see right now:

[image]

Comment: can you try wrapping the whole table with expanded widget

Comment: Thank you but Flutter did not like putting a table inside an Expanded widget :-(

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code outside of the Table widget, i.e. your layout.

Comment: i think you should use column for your usecase.

Comment: @user1032613 This is my whole application

Comment: It is indeed important to see more. If this is actually everything, put your table into a `Scaffold` as this would therefore solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Filling the space vertically is not as straight forward and not a default behaviour as it is for the horizontal part. It's because you usually don't want that behaviour: most of the time you want the content itself to determine the space vertically and make a view scrollable if it's too much content (and therefore not enough space available). There are also cases for horizontally scrollable elements, but thats special behaviour then.

If you insist on forcing to fill the space vertically, you need to do that manually. In this case, you have to determine the available space and set the heights of your elements. Best way to determine the available space is making use of the `LayoutBuilder` widget which gives you that information and updates its subtree if this information changes (since it's a builder widget).

Here you can see a rough and simplified solution using this approach and your example (I enabled the borders so its also visible:

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) => Table(
    border: TableBorder.all(),
    children: [
      TableRow(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
            child: Align(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('1'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
            child: Align(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('2'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      TableRow(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
            child: Align(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('3'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
            child: Align(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('4'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks, @Kounex.  I am trying to build a calculator keyboard and I don't really want to give the user the option to scroll.  I will try your solution but I was hoping for something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up giving up on using Table and instead used Column and Row widgets.  Here is my new code:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(child: TextButton(
            child: Text('1'),
            onPressed: () {},
          )),
          Expanded(child: TextButton(
              child: Text('2'),
              onPressed: () {},
          )),
        ]),
    ),
  ]
);
```